# How to get a PyObject corresponding to a builtin?

Tags: python, python-c-api

If I want to get a `PyObject` for something like, say, `sys.exc_info`, I can write

```
PyObject *sys_module = PyImport_Import("sys");
PyObject *sys_exc_info = PyObject_GetAttr(sys_module, "exc_info");
```

What if I want to get a `PyObject` corresponding to a builtin such as `list()` or `dir()`?  I've tried writing `PyImport_Import("builtins")` and `PyImport_AddModule("builtins")` and looking in the dictionary for that module, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Have you tried  PyObject* PyRun_String(const char *str, int start, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals) ? https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or Python 3? `builtins` is called `__builtin__` in Python 2. And if it's not working as expected, what actually happens?

Comment: @user2357112 if you respond as an answer i'll accept it, that was the problem.  I'm using both Python 2 and Python 3 (i.e. I need to be cross-compatible), but I was using `builtins` instead of choosing based on the version.  Works with I use `__builtin__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builtins` is called `__builtin__` in Python 2.